# Memory usage with multiple Texture2D based tiles in XNA

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

have started to write a simple tile scrolling routine. I need each tile to have a texture that has several “frames” for animation purposes. As all the tiles will use the same image I am concerned about memory usage. As each tile class uses Texture2D, does this mean that each tile instance will have a copy of the image or is the texture in Texture2D a reference back to a single texture? I have 42 tiles and I don’t want to have 42 copies of the same image in memory as this would be wasteful. What I want is 42 tiles referencing a single image as a Texture2D. Is this possible or should I approach this in a different way?

Comment: Why not give all the tiles a reference to the same Texture2D, loaded once?

Answer (score 0):

In C# it is normaly so that basic data structures have a by value pass which means that the value is copied to a new memory area. The affected datatypes are only the basic ones like string, int, float and so on.

But when you have an object and pass it as value or as parameter or just make an assignment to another var, not the entire object is copied. Instead the destination object takes the address in the memory of the old object and stores it as it's own object but still reffering to the original.

To copy or assign an object to a new memory space use the CopyTo()-Method.

Answer (score 0):

Texture2d references a texture in gpu, and you can hold the same texture twice in the graphics memory if you want, but this behaviour is not desirable, so the xna provides a content manager to avoid duplicates.

If you use Content.Load(asset) to load an asset texture, the content loads it, and  holds a reference to the new texture2d object, so next time you load that asset texture, it will return the same texture2d reference created before.

So you only have to use the content manager to avoid duplicities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question, but I believe you may want to look at using a texture atlas... Look at, for example, http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/texture-atlases-2